# Git-SCM for windows(64bit), when I try to launch git-gui, I got the error "Cannot parse Git version string"

Tags: git, version-control, git-gui

As the title, I got a problem to use Git on Windows7 (64bit).
Git Bash seems to work, but git-gui doesn't.

Also, I've installed 3rd party program like SourceTree, Tortoise Git and IntelliJ. They can't find git and get git version from mine.

I have tried re-install and install the older version like 2.8.x. Also, I tried set the Git in System Path. Everything didn't work so far.

My team uses the same PC and everyone has the same problem with me.

What else could we do for this?

Thank you in advance for all you guys' response :)

Comment: What's the path did you add to environment variables? It should be something like `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`.

Comment: As I said below, I already have tried to add the variable in my pc environment. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After install git, you should check your environment variables, make sure it's add in it. The format should be like `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`.

Comment: yeah, I already have tried to add the variable in my pc environment. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Did you use git GUI separately or combine with 3rd party programs like TortoiseGit when showing the error message?

Comment: I use git-gui separately. git-gui didn't work and 3rd party programs didn't find git.

Comment: What's the output if you use `git version` in git bash?

Comment: What about `git-gui version` in git bash? Did you use the default settings during install git?

Comment: I use only default settings and, I will check out `git-gui version` command in my office. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I got the same error as I launch git-gui directly. This would be problem...

Comment: I just install git on a win6 X64 PC, git GUI can work normally. You can test on other OS or higher windows version to check whether it works normally.

Comment: Actually, on my private computer, git works normally too. Just my office computer doesn't. I want to give you score, but I don't have enough reputation for that right now. I will give you the score later. I really appreciate for your help :)!!!